# Comparing two images for similarity using Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have an aerial, and a satellite image and I'm trying to measure the similarity of both images, and get a factor of how similar they are. What should I look into? I checked [fine-grained](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.4661v1.pdf) image similarity, but the problem is I don't know what will be the negative image since my two images are specific. So what should I read or check out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Learning a Similarity Metric Discriminatively, with Application to Face Verification](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/chopra-05.pdf)

A tutorial on how to implement the Siamese network described in the paper is [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html)